# Testing PHP Security

Tags: php, security, testing

I've been working on a script for some time now, making sure it's as secure as possible. My only problem is, how do I know if it's secure? I can't find anything online.

My script is a user management script, not for use, merely for practice.

I want to test for as many security holes as possible. XSS, CSRF, Session fixation/hijacking (important).

Comment: Seriously? Please, be more specific. Is this about password security? User restricted access? Session security? Penetration testing? We can't cover everything for you unless you give us something to bite. What does your script do and why does it need to be secure?

Comment: @Charles you're right. Sorry for the lack of information. Edited post.

Comment: Look on the right, the 'Related section'!

Comment: @markus-tharkun you've lost me... what do you mean?

Comment: Do some research on PHP security 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132134/php-security?rq=1

Comment: Did you google this or search SO at all? Such a broad topic has been covered a million times over.

Comment: @dtbarne *sigh* - sorry if I come across as rude, but did you read my question properly? I **know** how to make my code secure, but I want to make **absolute certain**.

Comment: If you *know* how, then I don't understand what you're asking. If you're looking for an extensive test, then maybe you're in the market to hire a whitehat hacker who will try hacking your application with various methods and tell you what issues he finds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is way too open to be answered in-depth here. However, here are some guides on how to protect against the possible attacks you mentioned:

- [XSS](http://stjhimy.com/posts/16-xss-protection)
- [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)
- [Session Hijacking](http://hydtechie.blogspot.de/2008/08/prevention-from-session-hijacking.html)

Remember: No system will ever be 100% secure. But these should be a good start. And [here](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/Top+10+Secure+Coding+Practices) are some basic things to keep in mind/to always do, like certain types of validation, etc.

Comment: This is my problem. My script is already secure - I **think** - but I'm paranoid, I want to know for certain that it's _more-or-less_ secure. Also, the links you gave me are ASP.NET tutorials.

Comment: Then hire a security expert to have a look at it.

Comment: Meh, not an option. I guess I'll just have to keep reading until I'm confident my code is secure. Thanks for the help, I'll mark your answer as best.